# Update GCP metadata via apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

basically I want to create a button in a spreadsheet which would run the equivalent of the following command

```
gcloud compute project-info add-metadata --project ${project} --metadata "test_label=test_value"
```

Is it possible? I'm not very familiar with the google javascript libraries.

Comment: If there's a http rest api for the same, possible through [tag:urlfetch]

Comment: So your intention is basically to modify a GCP project property (metadata) using Apps Script?

Comment: @MateoRandwolf yes

Answer (score 2):

So basically thanks to Mateo's pointers I was able to update the project metadata using this script:

```
function alex_test_function() {
 // get existing oauth token
 var theAccessTkn = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
 // get existing project metadata
 var response = 
 UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myProject', {
   headers: {
     Authorization: 'Bearer ' + theAccessTkn
   }
 });
 var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
 var metadata = data.commonInstanceMetadata

 fingerprint = metadata.fingerprint;
 new_metadata_items = metadata.items;

// update metadata
 var timestamp = new Date().getTime()
 setMetaKey(new_metadata_items, Session.getActiveUser().getEmail().split("@")[0], timestamp)

 var formData = {
  'fingerprint': fingerprint,
  'items': new_metadata_items
  };

 var postresponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myProject/setCommonInstanceMetadata", {
  'method' : 'post',
  'contentType': 'application/json',
  'payload' : JSON.stringify(formData),
  'headers': {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + theAccessTkn
   }
  });
}

function setMetaKey(metadata, key, value){
  // Function to add metadata or update if exists
  for (var i = 0; i < metadata.length; i++) {
    if (metadata[i].key === key) {
      metadata[i].value = value;
      return;
    }
  }
  metadata.push({key:key, value:value});
}
```

some gotchas, we need to set OAuth scopes to the AppScript manifest

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"]
}
```

and the user who's running the script needs to have permissions to edit the project metadata in the GCP project.

- I didn't experiment a lot with the scopes, it could be possible to execute the script with narrower scope instead of https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute

Answer (score 0):

At the moment of this answer, unfortunately, there is no method or class in Apps Script to change the metadata of a Google Cloud project. However, you can get and modify the document, script or user metadata using the class [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties).

However, if you want to edit your GCP project properties programmatically you will need to use [Google Cloud API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata) as it lets you modify these properties either from `gcloud`, its API or throughout the console.